# Batch: read list of files paths and names from text file and do something

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file and I have a .txt file containing informations formated as:

```
Folder_name/File
Another_older_name/AnotherFile
```

I am trying to do some actions on each .pdf file listed in the text file. I am currently in the directory where the folders listed in the .txt file are located.

**EDIT 2 after @Stephan's comment**

I tried the following code:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("Mytextfile.txt") do (
set line=%%A
pdftk %line%.pdf output Uncompressed%line%.txt uncompress
)
```

The result is nothing as the code does not seem to find the file `%line%.pdf`.

Changing the code in `do (...)` for

```
set line=%%A
@echo %line%
```

returns the content of the text file line by line.

Can someone explain me how to use the path and file name which are now stored in `%line%`?

*I am working on Windows 10.*

Comment: Either `for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (Mytexfle.txt) do...` or `for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("Mytexfle.txt") do...`. `For /?` explains why.

Comment: @Stephan Thank you, by adding `usebackq`I can now return the content of the text file but it is still not treated as a file path+name.

Comment: the Windows path separator is a backslash, not a slash: `Folder_name\File`. Can you show us the exact output of your script?

Comment: Also: are you sure the working folder is what you expect it to be?

Comment: @Stephan Thank you, I found a solution using your previous comment. I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, it might not be the best one but it works:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("Mytextfile.txt") do (
for %%B in ("%%A\..") do (
cd "%cd%\%%~nxB\"
pdftk %%~nxA.pdf output Uncompressed%%~nxA.txt uncompress
cd ..
)
)
```

It gets each line in the text file, store the last sub-directory in `%%~nxB`and the file name in `%%~nxA`. Then it goes in the directory, uncompress the file with `pdftk` and exits the directory.

Thanks for the help :)